# Check if character is in enum in C

Tags: c, enums, character

Let`s say I need to read a character from the keyboard and then check if this character is valid (have some function) in the current menu part.
So, if I am in firstMenu, search firstMenuKeys items, then if the character is found, call some function, otherwise throw this character.
Maybe the Enum is not suitable for this purpose.

```c
enum firstMenuKeys {

    UP = 72, 
    DOWN = 80,
    LEFT = 75, 
    RIGHT = 77,
    ENTER = 101,
    
};

enum secondMenuKeys {

    UP = 72, 
    DOWN = 80,
    ENTER = 101,
    
};




int main() {


    char c;
    c = getch();

    
    //check whether c is in firstMenuKeys


}
```

Comment: The `enum` is not directly relevant.  You'll probably need an array containing the valid values (which may be from the `enum`) and you'll need to search the array.  Alternatively, you can use a `switch` with the `enum` names as case labels, and a `default` case to catch those that are invalid.

Comment: Note that in C, enumeration constants have to  be distinct in the scope — see C11 [§6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers §3 and footnote 127](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2).  Your C code doesn't compile.  You might want to create an enumeration of key names, and arrays `firstMenuKeys` and `secondMenuKeys`.

Comment: An enum is essentially a collection of symbolic definitions, and there is no mechanism to enumerate or check membership. Since those seem to be all character values, one way to do it would be to store them in a string `const char firstKeys[] = "HPKMe";` then check `strchr(firstKeys, c)` for a match.

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` by itself is not well suited to checking a value against a set of valid values - C does not specify an operation to iterate over the enum values. One common way is to make use of an [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to create the enum and corresponding check function. Use of the X-macro allows the list values to be defined once and then be used in multiple contexts.

```
#define FIRST_MENU_KEYS \
    X(UP, 72) \ 
    X(DOWN, 80) \
    X(LEFT, 75) \ 
    X(RIGHT, 77) \
    X(ENTER, 101)

#define X(a, b) a = b,
enum firstMenuKeys {
    FIRST_MENU_KEYS
};

#define X(a, b) case a:
int isFirstMenuKey(char input)
{
    switch (input) {
        FIRST_MENU_KEYS
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```